# returning const reference to a member of a temporary object

Tags: c++, c++11, temporary-objects

What happens when a const reference to a a member of a temporary object is returned; What is the lifetime of that object;

E.g.

```
struct temp
{
  T m_mine;

  static temp make()
  {
    return temp();
  }
};

T const & foo()
{
  return temp::make().m_mine;
}
```

What is the behavior with c++98 and c++11?

Comment: "What is the lifetime of that object;" The reference is valid until the destructor of  object `struct temp` is evoked. In your example you don't return a temporary object but rather a `const` reference to a member variable (i.e., `m_mine`). If you return a reference to an object that has already been out of scope this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The const aspect of the return type will be ignored by the compiler I think BTW.

Comment: @101010 isn't that exactly what I am asking?

Comment: Destroying the `temp` also destroys its members, does it not? So the question is really when is the temporary object destroyed, and what happens if you try to access it afterward. "Undefined behavior" means it might actually appear to work OK, that is, you might be able to read data from the returned `T const &` without error, in some compiler on some system on a good day. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: @DavidK , I don't want, someone might have done though, and well just saying to her this is UD , she might not be persuaded. So there you are. I am not sure how many people here do have real production code experience in the MLOC range, but does not seem to be very many... Things like these just exist. You find them, have to correct them, but there is always a phase of persuasion and not everyone is has the standard in his head.

Comment: Do you mean you need to show someone that this is undefined behavior, or do you mean there is someone who thinks it's OK to rely on code that has undefined behavior? I work with code in the MLOC range, using a compiler that warns of returning a reference to a temporary, and we don't commit code to the baseline if it has these warnings. It's pretty simple, actually.

Comment: This code is illegal so there is no behaviour.

Comment: `this` cannot be used in a static member function

Comment: @M.M True, going for correction. Thanks

Comment: `return temp;` is also illegal, maybe you meant `return temp();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constness of the object or the referee type doesn't matter in this context: it's simply a return of a reference to an object that at that time has ceased to exist. Using the reference is then Undefined Behavior.

Likewise, if you bind a member reference to const, to an object, that does not prolong the life of the referee.

Object lifetime extension is only for the case of binding a *local* reference to an object, and only for the cases of reference to `const` object or rvalue reference.

---

<sup>The example code as it was at the time I wrote this, has several problems. Please only post **real code** (to the degree possible). And it should be pasted, not retyped.</sup>

<sup>(Also, since there is now at least 2 answers referring to the problems of the code, it's too late to correct it without possibly changing the context of the answers and thereby invalidating them. So it's important to get the code correct in the original posting. Worth keeping in mind for next SO question.)</sup>

Comment: Hey man, really I made this up this morning, there is no real code, and really not everyone works in the open source cloud . By the way, there is a way , you can edit your answer.

Comment: @g24l: It's true that SO reputation points generally don't say much more than how long you've been on SO and to what degree you have a social platform that votes you up. Still the relative rep scores here mean that Dietmar and I are both experienced SO users, so what we say about shortcomings in the questions should not be dismissed lightly. Also, we're both (now inactive) moderators of the comp.lang.c++.moderated Usenet group, which means we have some extensive experience in what suggestions can help people. Not that I personally always abide by it. :) But please do consider the advice.

Comment: well it says that you have a lot of free time to do suggestions. :p , please do consider my advice and get of the high horse (you have a cowboy as avatar) and edit your post. What part of the collaborative site did you miss. Thanks for the advice , and truly have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect in multiple accounts before it is even getting to compile:

- there is at least a semicolon missing after the type declaration
- the code uses the non-`static` member `make()`  as if it is a `static` function

Once getting over that: the reference returned refers to a subobject of an object which is destroyed after the `return` statement is executed and before anything can get hold of it. That is, there is a stale reference return. Any access to this reference will result in undefined behavior. If you are lucky, the program crashes at this point. If you are unlucky it does something you like it to happen. For example it may "work" until the program is demonstrated to a client or an investor at which point it may decide to rather display insults.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the corrections, really missed that. Please put suggestions in comments though, not in answers. Thumbs up.